# Xcode share run script build phase between projects in a workspace

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftlint

Is there a way in Xcode to share a run script build phase across multiple projects in a workspace?

I am using [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint) to enforce coding styles, but I don't want to manually add the necessary run script to all of the projects (that I maintain, not 3rd party) in my Xcode project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, but it is a solution specific to SwiftLint, not any run script.

My solution that seems to work fine is to pick whichever target I will normally be building and only put the run script for that target, but make the run script specify the `--path` to be one directory up. Since SwiftLint runs recursively in all subdirectories this works fine:

`swiftlint lint --path "$SRCROOT"/..`